# ViewException : Trying to get property 'follows' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, web

I am getting the exception

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException : Trying to get property 'follows' of non-object (View: E:\tweety\resources\views\_friends-lists.blade.php)
```

From this code:

```php
<h3 class="font-bold text-lg mb-4 block">Following</h3>
<ul>
  @foreach (auth()->user()->follows as $user)
    <li class="mb-2">
      <div class="flex items-center text-sm">
        <img src="{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="" class="rounded-full mr-2">{{ $user->name }}</div>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a signed in user at that point? If there is no user signed in, the `auth()->user()` returns null.

Comment: To check whether you are returning a `User` try doing `{{ dd(auth()->user()) }}` before your `@foreach` loop and check that it isn't returning `null`

Answer (score -1):

```
<h3 class="font-bold text-lg mb-4 block">Following</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach (DB::table("users")->where("follows",auth()->user()->id)->get() as $user)
        <li class="mb-2">
            <div class="flex items-center text-sm">
                <img src="{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="" class="rounded-full mr-2">{{ $user->name }}</div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Now getting this : Missing required parameters for [Route: profile] [URI: profiles/{user}]. (View: E:\tweety\resources\views_sidebar-links.blade.php) , code :